# How to get executing line number, method name and file name at runtime in Objective C(Dynamically)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, logging, dynamic

I am developing an iphone application. I want log file name, method name and line number of the method while it is executing. I have used following code for getting the required values.

`NSLog(@"Hi!  I'm in method %s at %s:%u", __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__);`

But, I want to log the values dynamically without using NSLogs in code.

I have tried environment variable `NSObjCMessageEnabled: YES` which gives only method names, but I want file name and line number as well. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean "log the values dynamically without NSLog"?

Comment: for NSLogs, we need to add code(NSLogs... ) in our existing code. But I dont want to add any code in my existing code. It should give line numbers of each methods without using NSlogs.. same as 'NSObjCMessageEnabled: YES is used for method entry logging.

Comment: Your request is not logical. You want a message for every line of code that executes? That would give you nothing more than the exact order of your statements, hardly useful for any purpose.

Comment: Not every line of code. Only the method entry line number of each method. which is useful for me for maintaining logs and bug/issue fixing. Please let me know if you know the solution.